# Big O constant c and n for algorithms

Tags: big-o

I assume that a particular example in my book is wrong. But am I correct?

```
Example: 3log n + 2 is O(log n)

Justification: 3log n + 2 <= 5 log n, for n>=2.
```

I understand how they get the c=5 (since they take the coefficients and add them up). But I don't see how for n=2 for instance, the left function is smaller than the right one.

If I fill in 2 in n:

3 log 2 + 2 = 2.903 and 5 log 2 = 1.5051.

Only till n=10, the left function is actually smaller or equal than the right one. 
Is my assumption right?

Comment: As a side note, the value for which the inequality is true does not matter as long as it is a constant.

Comment: So the thing that only really matters is the c, which is in this case the 5?

Comment: It is: the inequality is true ``for n >= c``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log in this case is 2 based, not 10 based.

```
3log(2) + 2 = 3 + 2 = 5
5log(2) = 5
```

and it is true that 5 <= 5

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on Peter's answer, the base of the logarithm is typically assumed to be base 2 when analyzing run times. It's not necessary to specify the base in the O() notation, since logarithms of different bases differ from each other only by a constant factor. (In this example, `log_10(x) / log_2(x) = log(2)/log(10) = ~0.30103`.) This constant factor is not relevant to the asymptotic run time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! At the moment I have to low rep to vote your comment up! I will get back to this when I can.